# Put java class to nashorn's global scope

Tags: java, nashorn

I use sandboxed Nashorn like this:

```
ScriptEngine engine = new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine(
            new String[]{"--no-java", "--no-syntax-extensions", "--optimistic-types=true", "--language=es6"},
            null);
```

But I want to use a single particular class in my javascript. How to do that?
For example, I have a class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public void m1()
    {
        System.out.println("This is m1");
    }
    public void m2()
    {
        System.out.println("This is m2");
    }
}
```

And I want to use it in the script like

```
let a=new MyClass();
a.m1();
a.m2();
```

How to do that?
Thank you

Comment: If you can't use java why don't rewrite method in javascript?

Comment: @user7294900 because I need a single java class, accessible from js, as I wrote in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Bindings` to provide java objects to the `ScriptEngine`:

```
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory;

import javax.script.Bindings;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;


public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     ScriptEngine engine = new NashornScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine(
            new String[]{"--no-java", "--no-syntax-extensions", "--optimistic-types=true", "--language=es6"},
            null);

    Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
    bindings.put("myclass", new MyClass());
    engine.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE);

    String code = "myclass.m1();";

    try {
        engine.eval(code, bindings);
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("This is m1");
    }

    public void m2(String str) {
        System.out.println("This is m2 " + str);
    }

    public void m3(Class claz) {
        System.out.println(claz);
    }

}
```

or if `MyClass` really needs to be instantiated in the JS code you could do **(works with Java >=9)**:

```
    Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
    bindings.put("myclass", StaticClass.forClass(MyClass.class));

    var code = "var a = new myclass(); a.m1();";

    try {
        engine.eval(code, bindings);
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried that? I have got `Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: null is not a function in <eval> at line number 52` when I try to call class method from js. Will check second example and let you know

Comment: Second example gives me `Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: myclass is not a function in <eval> at line number 51`

Comment: I added a complete example which I tested successfully with Java 1.8, 9, 10, 11 , 13 and 14.

Comment: Ok, I see now. But as it stated in the question, I need to put a class in the global scope. I cannot use another bindings

Comment: even if I add  `engine.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE);` it works for me

Comment: Well, thank you very much! I swear, I did the same before, but now I removed everything and rewrote it from scratch and it works! You scared it somehow, thank you!